# Using the same form to add new item and edit existing in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to use the same form to add new item and update existing. I tried to do it on my own, unfortunately unsuccessfully. I just created method findItemToEdit, but I do not know how to pass the information to existing form, edit it and update the item. As I am new in React I got a little confused. Could anybody give me help, please.
Her is my context.js file:

```
    import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";
    import uuid from "react-uuid";
    import { warehouseProducts } from "./data";

    const ProductContext = createContext();

    class ProductProvider extends Component {
      state = {
        products: [],
        detailProduct: "",
        editItem: null,
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        this.setProducts();
      }

      setProducts = () => {
        let products = [];
        warehouseProducts.forEach((item) => {
          const singleItem = { ...item };
          products = [...products, singleItem];
        });
        this.setState(() => {
          return { products: products };
        });
      };

      getItem = (id) => {
        const product = this.state.products.find((item) => item.id === id);
        return product;
      };

      productDetailHandler = (id) => {
        const product = this.getItem(id);
        this.setState(() => {
          return { detailProduct: product };
        });
      };

      changeHandler = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        const { newProductItem } = this.state;
        this.setState({
          newProductItem: { ...newProductItem, [event.target.name]: value },
        });
      };

      addItemHandler = ( event, name, ean, type, weight, color, quantity, price, info) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.target.reset();
        const { newProductItem } = this.state;
        const products = [
          ...this.state.products,
          { ...newProductItem, id: uuid() },
        ];

        this.setState({ products, newProductItem: {} });
      };


      removeProduct = (id) => {
        const products = this.state.products.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
        this.setState({ products: products });
      };

      // find item for editing
      findItemToEdit = (id) => {
        const product = this.getItem(id);
        this.setState({ editItem: product });
      };



      render() {
        return (
          <ProductContext.Provider
            value={{
              ...this.state,
              productDetailHandler: this.productDetailHandler,
              changeHandler: this.changeHandler,
              addItemHandler: this.addItemHandler,
              removeProduct: this.removeProduct,
              findItemToEdit: this.findItemToEdit,
            }}
          >
            {this.props.children}
          </ProductContext.Provider>
        );
      }
    }

    const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

    export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer };
```

and Form component:

```
      import React, { Component } from "react";
      import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
      import { ProductConsumer } from "../../context";
      import "./ProductForm.css";

      class ProductForm extends Component {

        render() {
          return (
            <ProductConsumer>
              {(value) => (
                <form
                  className="Form"
                  onSubmit={value.addItemHandler}

                >
                  <h1>Item Input Form</h1>
                  <p>
                    Item Name{" "}
                    <input
                      onChange={value.changeHandler}
                      className="Form_input"
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      value={value.products.name}
                      required
                    />
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    EAN{" "}
                    <input
                      onChange={value.changeHandler}
                      className="Form_input"
                      type="text"
                      name="ean"
                      value={value.products.ean}
                      required
                    />
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Type{" "}
                    <input
                      onChange={value.changeHandler}
                      className="Form_input"
                      type="text"
                      name="type"
                      value={value.products.type}
                      required
                    />
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Weight, kg{" "}
                    <input
                      onChange={value.changeHandler}
                      className="Form_input"
                      type="number"
                      name="weight"
                      value={value.products.weight}
                      required
                    />
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Color{" "}
                    <input
                      onChange={value.changeHandler}
                      className="Form_input"
                      type="text"
                      name="color"
                      value={value.products.color}
                      required
                    />
                  </p>

                  <p>
                    Quantity{" "}
                    <input
                      onChange={value.changeHandler}
                      className="Form_input"
                      type="number"
                      name="quantity"
                      value={value.products.quantity}
                      required
                    />
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Price, ${" "}
                    <input
                      onChange={value.changeHandler}
                      className="Form_input"
                      type="number"
                      name="price"
                      value={value.products.price}
                      required
                    />
                  </p>

                  <p>
                    Description{" "}
                    <textarea
                      onChange={value.changeHandler}
                      className="Form_info"
                      type="text"
                      name="info"
                      value={value.products.info}
                      required
                    />
                  </p>

                  <div>
                    <button className="Btn" type="submit">
                      ADD
                    </button>
                    <Link to="/products">
                      <button className="Back">BACK TO PRODUCTS</button>
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                </form>
              )}
            </ProductConsumer>
          );
        }
      }

      export default ProductForm;
```

Comment: @R J could you add a specific issue you are encountering with this? Is there an exception, or is it just an unexpected behavior? More details would help provide you with the answer you need

Comment: This code is to add new item. I would like to get existing item from the list to the form, edit it and update the list.